# Run a C# .cs file from a PowerShell Script

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a `PowerShell V2` script that moves some files around and installs some services. However I would like to call and run a .cs file about halfway through the PowerShell Script. I have found plenty of articles on calling `PowerShell` from `C#` but none the opposite way around. I would just like the C# file to run once then continue running the PowerShell script.

If anyone could point me in the direction of an article explaining how to accomplish this or if you know yourself and could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't "run a .cs file"... it isn't a script. It'll be part of a larger project, a console or wpf app maybe. Can you give any more details on the file and what it's a part of?

Comment: Yes sorry, it is a `Console Application` that edits an `XML` file that I have. It mostly just changes text in the XML file, nothing too complicated. It only has one class called `class1`.

Comment: So why don't you call/run the compiled executable instead? If it takes parameters, you can give it parameters.

Comment: This example might help [Using CSharp (C#) code in Powershell scripts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx)

Comment: you should read about scriptCS. It allows you to run *.cs files with PowerShell. You may find more detailed information [here](http://scriptcs.net/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong thing.  Put your C# into an assembly, and call its public classes, functions and methods from PowerShell, just like you would call the .NET Framework from Powershell.

If you really want to compile and run C# source from PowerShell, see
[Weekend Scripter: Run C# Code from Within PowerShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20141005190814/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/30/weekend-scripter-run-c-code-from-within-powershell.aspx).

Answer (score 54):

I saw no reason why we couldn't run a `.cs` file directly from PowerShell, so I took Keith's snip and added the missing `Get-Content` parts to do literally what the OP asks for.  No need to compile your code, just edit the `-Path` argument to point to your `.cs` file.

```bsh
$source = Get-Content -Path "A:\basic.cs"
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$source"

# Call a static method
[BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)

# Create an instance and call an instance method
$basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
$basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
```

### Basic.cs

```cs
public class BasicTest
{
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }

    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-Content` may need `-Raw`

Comment: I copied this wrong too. You don't need `-Raw` if you use their code and stringify: `"$source"`

Comment: `Get-Content` with `-Raw` and simply passing the result as a variable should be more reliable.

Comment: It's obvious if you know, but if there's a namespace in the `.cs` you'll need to include that when calling from powershell: `[Full.Namespace.BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)`

Answer (score 34):

You can use `Add-Type` to compile C# code and add it to the current PowerShell session.  Then you call the C# code like you would any other .NET framework code.  This is an example from the `man page` on Add-Type:

```
PS C:\>$source = @"
public class BasicTest
{
  public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
  public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
    return (a * b);
    }
}
"@

PS C:\>Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source
PS C:\>[BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)
PS C:\>$basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
PS C:\>$basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
```

Comment: I tried this Add-Type example in Powershell Core v. 7.1.4 (the Original Poster's question was about Powershell V2) running on MacOS, and it still works great today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can run c# script from *.bat file:

1. create c# script (e.g. Program.cs) with `public static void Main()`
   method
2. create *.bat (e.g. Run.bat) file and place this code:

```bash
@ECHO off
Echo Please run as administrator
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
set csDir=%cd%\Program.cs
powershell ^
set-executionpolicy remotesigned; ^
$source = Get-Content -Raw -Path %csDir%; ^
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$source"; ^
[Program]::Main()
```

3. Run

Answer (score 0):

A `.cs` file can be directly read.

```
Add-Type -Path 'program.cs'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1