# How to run DB migrations in console application in team services deploy task?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I'm looking to move an ASP.NET Core application into Visual Studio Team Services for continuous integration and continuous deploy. My application is currently built and deployed "manually":

1. Build by "publishing" to Web Deploy package in Visual Studio.
2. Apply DB-migrations (implemented using [Simple.Migrations](https://github.com/canton7/Simple.Migrations)) by running a console application (built along with te web app in step 1) on the target server.
3. Deploy the built web app using Web Deploy on target server.

And now I would like to automate this process using Visual Studio Team Services. Building the web app (step 1) and deploying it to an Azure App Service (step 3)seems pretty straight forward. But I'm not sure how to apply my Simple.Migrations database migrations (step 2). Is it possible to run a console application (built along side the web app during the build phase) in the deploy phase? A task for running command line scripts certainly exists but I'm not sure what you can actually do with it.

Note that I would like to use the hosted agent (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in task called: [Deploy: PowerShell on Target Machines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines). This task uses Windows Remote Management (WinRM) to access on-premises physical computers or virtual computers that are domain-joined or workgroup-joined. This task can run both PowerShell scripts and PowerShell-DSC scripts.

Not sure if you could put your console application code in a ps script or directly [Run a C# .cs file from a Powershell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868273/run-a-c-sharp-cs-file-from-a-powershell-script) . Another way is using PowerShell  run DB migrations. A sample for your reference: [Use PowerShell to Migrate SQL Server Instances (db, logins, jobs, etc)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Use-PowerShell-to-Migrate-86c841df)