# Get input from the user using ReadLine in c# code that runs as part of PowerShell script in PowerShell ISE

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-ise

I need to prompting users for input in C# part of the code, but it doesn't work for me (gets empty input automagically) when run from PowerShell ISE. Code works as expected when run from just regular PowerShell command prompt (asks for the name)

```
$id = get-random
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace Application
{
    public class Program$id
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your sweet name....");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello *"+name+" %" );
        }
   }
}
"@
Add-type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
iex "[Application.Program$id]::Main()"
```

When run in ISE the output is following (notice there is no chance to provide input):

```
       PS C:\Users\Pavithra Kathirvel\Desktop> C:\Users\Pavithra Kathirvel\Desktop\demo.ps1
       Please enter your sweet name....
       Hello * %
```

Comment: This is not something "a beginner to Powershell and C#" would do... So with this cleared can you please explain what your actual goal is?

Comment: Hey, dood..I need to get inputs from the user using c# code which must be comforting to run through PowerShell ise

Comment: You might be better off developing a PowerShell module using C#, that way they can use it from PowerShell scripts easily.
https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/18/writing-a-powershell-module-in-c-part-1-the-basics/

Answer (score -2):

As a beginner start with the basics in C# and powershell. If you are able to use one, it will be easier for you to learn the other. Also there are parts, which are in powershell faster than in c# and less code.

If you still want to execute your C# code in powershell, have a look at this link, it will run the script from a .cs file 
[Run a C# .cs file from a PowerShell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868273/run-a-c-sharp-cs-file-from-a-powershell-script)

Also here is a really good tutorial for using c# in powershell:
https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2016/03/19/executing-c-code-using-powershell-script/

Comment: None of those links actually answers the initial question. I still do not know why Console.ReadLine() in the posted question is not actually working. Works fine in a standalone run of the c# code though.