# How can .NET code can be used in RunDeck software?

Tags: rundeck

How can **.NET** code be used in **RunDeck** software?

If yes, please provide a sample. I have used **PowerShell** code but not able find any **.NET** placeholder.

Comment: Did you mean to develop Rundeck plugins through .NET? (that's not possible only through Java or bash). But if you want to run over PowerShell, maybe following a Powershell script step (inline or "external")  in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868351/10426011

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, the best approach is to call your code via PowerShell script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868273/run-a-c-sharp-cs-file-from-a-powershell-script/24868351#24868351).